# PHP loading template file and replacing placeholders.

Tags: php, function, file-get-contents, str-replace

I have a html template file called "template.tmpl". In the template I have a few placeholders like {{NAME}} and {{USERNAME}}. I am then loading the template file into a variable called $template using file_get_contents. I then put the $template variable through a function which deals with replacing a series of placeholders.

My code is below and seems to be working fine. But wanted some input if there was any way to improve or make it more efficient?

Thanks

```
function replace_tags($string){
    $vars = array('{{NAME}}'=>'Bob', '{{USERNAME}}'=>'user_name', '<?'=>'', '?>'=>'');
    return str_replace(array_keys($vars), $vars, $string);
}

$template = file_get_contents('template.tmpl', true);

echo replace_tags($template);
```

Comment: Seeing as you're after feedback (ways to improve, things you may have missed, ...) [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to post this question. PS: There are many, many fine templating engines out there already. No need to reinvent the wheel. Since you're using `{{ NAME }}` placeholders, [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) might be worth looking into (it's available as PHP extension, or as a PHP lib). We've been using it for a couple of years, and are very happy with it

Comment: Thank you. i didnt know about codereview.